# select totals from multiple tables group by month SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables :

```
`achat` (`id_achat`, `id_frn`, `date`, `taux`, `total`)
`vente` (`id_vente`, `id_vendeur`, `date`, `id_client`, `total`)
`avance` (`id_avance`, `id_achat`, `cout`, `date`, `mode`)
`avancevente` (`id_av`, `id_vente`, `cout`, `date`, `mode`)
```

what I want is to show in one php row the sum(total) of `achat`'s table, `vente`'s table and sum(total-cout) from the two tables `achat` and `avance`and the last one sum(total-cout) from the two tables `vente` and `avancevente` group by month and years.

thanks

Comment: Well, then go ahead and post where you get stuck.

Comment: Post up an SQLfiddle showing what you've tried and (somewhere - maybe in comments) the desired result